# How can I create a Choropleth by combining a polygon GeoPanda with a point GeoPanda?

Tags: python, geopandas, mapping, pandas, choropleth

I have two GeoPanda dataframes, one with the location of shops with point coordinates in the geometry column, and one with London boroughs with polygons in the geometry column.

My usual approach with creating a choropleth is to loop through each borough and check how many points are contained in each borough, before assigning that value to the borough, for instance:

```
Points_Within = []
for B in borough_df:
    Points_Within.append(len(Shop_df.intersects(B.geometry)))
borough_df['Points Within'] = Points_Within
```

This is fine (albeit cumbersome with large dfs), however, I refuse to accept that there isn't a cleaner way of doing it.

If anyone can shed some light on a nicer way to do this I would be very appreciative!

James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use spatial join:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

polygons = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/sweden_hexgrid.shp")
polygon_id_field = 'id'
points = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/ancient_remains.shp")

sjoin = gpd.sjoin(polygons, points, how='left', op='intersects')
count = sjoin.groupby(polygon_id_field)[polygon_id_field].count()
count.name='pointcount'
polygons = pd.merge(left=polygons, right=count, left_on=polygon_id_field, right_index=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,8))
polygons.plot(column = 'pointcount', cmap = 'Purples', ax=ax, legend=True, 
              legend_kwds={'label':'Number of sites with ancient remains'})
polygons.geometry.boundary.plot(color=None, edgecolor='k',linewidth = 1, ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: sjoin!?! How have I never heard of this, thank you for the comprehensive answer.

Comment: A small follow-up question - Sometimes one of the points may not fall exactly into one of the polygons (for instance the London polygon file I have has a cut out where the River Thames is), is there a similarly as effective approach which assigns the points to the closest polygon? I have used the argmin of polygons.distance(point) before, however that is rather slow!